# asp.net website migrating from 2003 server to 2012 server

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7, iis-7.5, web-deployment

My asp.net website was hosted in Windows 2003 server with the domain name `www.mysite.com`, I stopped this website. We are moving this application into a Windows 2012 server and the website was deployed successfully, but this domain name is not working: `www.mysite.com`. When I removed the the domain name by using `localhost` I am able to access the website.

What is issue with configuring the domain name? (www.mysite.com)

I am getting the error below:

> This error (HTTP 400 Bad Request) means that Internet Explorer was able to connect to the web server, but the webpage could not be found because of a problem with the address.

Comment: have you updated the dns entries for your domain? Have you added the correct bindings for the new ip to IIS?

Comment: I given the Correct binding details but i don't have any idea how to update the dns entries, if you know can you please explain @JanR

Comment: The dns entries will only need to be  updated if the ip address of the website has changed. Effectively linking mysite.com to the new IP address. Where to update this depends on your Hosting provider/domain registrar or whether you are running your own dns servers.